Geometric Modeling of Arbtirary $3$D CAD surfaces
Given an arbitrary $3$D CAD model (in STL, STEP format), is it possible to convert the model into a function $z = f(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are points on the $3$D model/surface? In other words, how do we fit an equation on an arbitrary $3$D CAD model/surface?
I convert the STL file into a point cloud using CloudCompare software and then export the pointcloud to a .txt. From the txt file, I obtain the $x,y,z$ coordinates, and finally, I obtain surface fit using the cftool (curve fitting toolbox of MATLAB). The result is nowhere same as the original STL file.
STL File
Point Cloud Data
MATLAB Code


Whats your purpose for a x,y function? The reason it is multiple pieces is that its easier to deal with (or even the only way). But theres lots you can do but only for a subset of usecases. There is no genral answer to the question.

Thank you for the response @joojaa. Actually I am new to the field of geometric modeling and am still learning. As long as I am able to accurately reconstruct the original model it is fine to use multiple functions. In MATLAB cftool, the following interpolation options are available: 1. Nearest neighbor 2. Linear 3. Cubic spline 4. Biharmonic 5. Thin-plate spline. Unfortunately, none is able to reconstruct the original model.

The step model allready is a function

Basically it's a fourier/heisenberg bandwidth problem. If you take a 2d slice through your object and try and do a fourier analysis on it you'll see you need infinite bandwidth to get a good model.

Thanks @GregLocock for the response. I have edited the question to include the STL file, point cloud data (saved as MATLAB .mat file) and the MATLAB code for converting the STL file to a 3D surface equation. I hope this makes my question more clear.

Your question is clear. You are trying to do the impossible. A point cloud generated from an arbitrary curve with step type functions in it cannot be turned back into an absolutely accurate profile using curve fitting, unless it has infinite points.

You could try doing the curve fitting in some sort of a grid approach, to enhance the accuracy locally. (and then maybe try to fit each grid to each other using some gradient-similarity or another idea.)

of course this has the drawback of coming up with a piecewise function (maybe even without continuity).

What im wodering though is since the STEP file allready is a piecewise b-spline, why convert it at all? Why not use the functions that are allready there and forego secondary fitting completely. Not much you can do to STL though it was mangled before you got it so no resampling of any kind. Again all of the advice we can give come at the end to what your actually trying to achieve.

Thanks everyone for their insightful comments. I think I am now beginning to figure out some solution and my approach so far is apparently not the right way to go. The PointCloud software samples points randomly between the mesh triangles. Of course, it is not possible to reconstruct the original model using these random points by mans of curve fitting.

So the problem simply boils down to Conversion of Solid/STL/STEP file into a geomtery. Lets assume for now that thickness of the STL file is unimportant and only the outer surface/shell/geometry of the solid is required. What is the way to go? I got to know that some (but not all) CAD softwares can convert solids to geometry but I am not sure how.
